# control vlc process in c#

Tags: c#, process, vlc

I'm running a c# program and I need to play a video on vlc on another process and feed it with commands.
I'm not looking for something like `axVLCPlugin21`

I only need basic play/pause/volume commands.
What is the easiest way to achieve this?

I tried this, but the stdin writing failed

`Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\...\a.mp4");
p.StandardInput.Write("comand");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also found the console Std In redirection didn't work to the VLC process. The only way I could get the VLC console interface to work is with [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which isn't a very nice way of doing it.

VLC also supports socket connections for the same interface though, and this seems to work quite well. Here's an example of how to connect and send/receive commands and responses.

```
static void Main()
{
    IPEndPoint socketAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 54165);
    var vlcServerProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe", "-I rc --rc-host " + socketAddress.ToString());

    try
    {
        Socket vlcRcSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        vlcRcSocket.Connect(socketAddress);
        // start another thread to look for responses and display them
        Task listener = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Receive(vlcRcSocket));

        Console.WriteLine("Connected. Enter VLC commands.");

        while(true)
        {
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            if (command.Equals("quit")) break;
            Send(vlcRcSocket, command);
        }

        Send(vlcRcSocket, "quit"); // close vlc rc interface and disconnect
        vlcRcSocket.Disconnect(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        vlcServerProcess.Kill();
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket socket, string command)
{
    // send command to vlc socket, note \n is important
    byte[] commandData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}\n", command));
    int sent = socket.Send(commandData);
}

private static void Receive(Socket socket)
{
    do
    {
        if (socket.Connected == false)             
            break;
        // check if there is any data
        bool haveData = socket.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead);

        if (haveData == false) continue;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (haveData)
            {
                int received = socket.Receive(buffer);
                mem.Write(buffer, 0, received);
                haveData = socket.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray()));
        }    

    } while (true);         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, sockets worked surprisingly easy!. SendKeys is kind of the aproach I was looking for, just for a simple proof of concept, still, it is far uglier than what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect the standard input of the process you are creating. See the sample on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page for details.

Comment: thanks! But once with stdin correctly configured it still doesn't respond to any command :S